# Different size of unordered_map across gcc versions

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

The value of `sizeof(std::unordered_map<int, int>)` seems to be different in different gcc versions around gcc 4.6—4.9 on linux:

- 4.6: 56
- 4.7: 64
- 4.8: 48
- 4.9 & newer: 56

([test code on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df67cefc6a12741)) (the same for other specializations)

This obviously results in memory access problems when linking together libraries that were compiled with different gcc versions.

Namely, a problem that I am facing right now is one library, say `libfoo`, that exposes some `class Foo` as its interface. That is, the library provides the `foo.h` header file:

```
class Foo {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    int val;
public:
    Foo(): val(42) {}
    int getVal(); 
};
```

and also provides the compiled library `libfoo.so` that contains the binary code for `Foo::getVal()` that accesses `Foo::val`. The library was compiled with gcc 4.6 and so assumes that `val` has offset of 56 bytes from `Foo` start.

Now I write my program that uses `libfoo`. I write

```
#include <foo.h>    
int bar() {
    Foo foo;
    return foo.getVal();
}
```

I build my program with gcc 4.8. It assumes that `unordered_map` has size of 48 bytes, and so allocates only `48+sizeof(int)` for Foo object. As a result, `foo.getVal()` accesses data outside of the object.

---

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to workaround this problem? For example, making gcc 4.8 use the `unordered_map` from gcc 4.6? In fact, the problem is only allocationg proper memory size, as all the actual work with the `map` field happens only inside `libfoo.so`. I think I can do some raw-pointer magic by explicitly allocating more memory and doing placement new, but this seems to be really unreliable and prone to memory leaks.
2. Am I right that this is a non-usual situation, probably because `unordered_map` implementation was still considered experimental in gcc <4.9, and so no similar problems can occur with other standard classes that are not experimental?
3. If no, then how such problems should be mitigated in general?

---

Note that it does not seem to be a problem of linking to a particular version of libstdc++; the problem is calculating how much memory should be allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1:

I would use the following wrapper:

```
constexpr int DesirableFooSize = 60;
constexpr bool FooTooSmall = sizeof(Foo) < DesirableFooSize;

class FooWrapper final : private Foo {
    std::enable_if<FooTooSmall, std::array<int8_t, DesirableFooSize - sizeof(Foo)>>::type x;
public:
    using Foo::getInt;
    using Foo::Foo;
    Foo* getFooPointer() {
        return this;
    }
    Foo& getFooReference() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And all code in your program should use `FooWrapper` instead of just plain `Foo`. This will guarantee that you always allocate exactly 60 bytes for each `Foo` object, never forget to free this additional memory, and the additional memory is not accessible. `Private` inheritance and an explicit casting functions are written here intentionally, to make you think twice when you want to cast `FooWrapper` to `Foo` or do something with pointers or references.